# Correct Selection of SQL server instance db owner login name

Tags: sql-server, windows

I am attempting to connect RSA Archer (5.2) to an instance of SQL server 2008 r2 on WS 2008 R2.
When Archer attempts it's initial connection I get -
*The ConnectString property has not been initialized. Please ensure that all databases on the server have a dbowner.*

That instance I was connecting to did indeed have a db owner and it had
a DBO role too. I suspect it is the login account that I am associating to this DB owner user ID.

Does anyone have any suggestions how I can get around this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mentioned the 'instance had a dbowner' but in SQL Server databases can have dbowners, not instances.  Did you ever do a backup/restore from other systems?  Perhaps you have an orphaned users.  Also have you checked sql profiler for failed login attempts?

Comment: Are there any messages in the SQL log that have more detail on the login failure?  Even if it's just an error number that will help track down what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about your specific case, but I would check to see if the login you're using is a member of the dbo role in the database you're trying to connect to.  You can query role membership using this query:

```
use YourDatabase;

select 
    r.name role_name,
    u.name db_login,
    u.type_desc
from (select * from sys.database_principals where type = 'R') r
    join sys.database_role_members rm on (r.principal_id = rm.role_principal_id)
    join (select * from sys.database_principals where type != 'R') u on rm.member_principal_id = u.principal_id
where r.name = 'db_owner'
order by r.principal_id,u.type_desc,u.name;
```

If you need to add the login to the DBO role:

```
Use YourDatabase;
exec sp_addrolemember 'db_owner','FOO\bar';
```